# Is it possible to cancel a BeginRead on a NamedPipeServerStream without closing the pipe?

Tags: .net

What the title says, really.

I have a named pipe. I would like to attempt a read, but if it doesn't succeed after a timeout I'd like to still be able to use the pipe afterwards.

Is this possible with `NamedPipeServerStream`, or do I have to rethink the entire approach?

So far the only way I've found of cancelling a `BeginRead` is by disposing of the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I didn't find a way. I still cancel a read that is taking too long by disposing of the stream, meaning that it can't be used at all afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

The `BeginRead` returns an `IAsyncResult`, capture this in the scope of the class.

Then create a timer with the desired timeout, in the callback method call `EndRead`, passing the `IAsyncResult` returned from the initial `BeginRead`.

Edit:
I have been doing some research and the best solution I have found is to dispose of the ServerStream (which does dispose of the Pipe itself).

Comment: EndRead blocks until something has been read. How do I prevent that?